# Enumerate over list of integers and access list value by index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve a LeetCode problem and am not sure why what I have done does not work.  Moreso than simply getting a working solution, I am trying to figure out why this approach does not work.  The error that I am getting is:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
    if value[0] == 0:
Line 22 in intToRoman (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().intToRoman(param_1)
Line 123 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 134 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

So, it seems to be complaining about the section where I enumerate my list and try to access the value of the index.  Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def intToRoman(self, num: int) -> str:
        
        answer = ""
        
        # Calculate length of num
        num = str(num)
        numLength = len(num)
        
        # Convert num to list of individual digits and reverse
        numArray = [int(digit) for digit in num]
        numArray.reverse()    
        
        # Build Roman Numeral
        firstDigit = ""
        secondDigit = ""
        thirdDigit = ""
        fourthDigit = ""
        
        for count, value in enumerate(numArray):
            if numLength >= 1:
                if value[0] == 0:
                    firstDigit = None
                if value[0] == 1:
                    firstDigit = "I"
                if value[0] == 2:
                    firstDigit = "II"
                if value[0] == 3:
                    firstDigit = "III"
                if value[0] == 4:
                    firstDigit = "IV"
                if value[0] == 5:
                    firstDigit = "V"
                if value[0] == 6:
                    firstDigit = "VI"
                if value[0] == 7:
                    firstDigit = "VII"
                if value[0] == 8:
                    firstDigit = "VIII"
                if value[0] == 9:
                    firstDigit = "IX"
            if numLength >= 2:
                if value[1] == 0:
                    secondDigit = None
                if value[1] == 1:
                    secondDigit = "X"
                if value[1] == 2:
                    secondDigit = "XX"
                if value[1] == 3:
                    secondDigit = "XXX"
                if value[1] == 4:
                    secondDigit = "XL"
                if value[1] == 5:
                    secondDigit = "L"
                if value[1] == 6:
                    secondDigit = "LX"
                if value[1] == 7:
                    secondDigit = "LXX"
                if value[1] == 8:
                    secondDigit = "LXXX"
                if value[1] == 9:
                    secondDigit = "XC"
            if numLength >= 3:
                if value[2] == 0:
                    thirdDigit = None
                if value[2] == 1:
                    thirdDigit = "C"
                if value[2] == 2:
                    thirdDigit = "CC"
                if value[2] == 3:
                    thirdDigit = "CCC"
                if value[2] == 4:
                    thirdDigit = "CD"
                if value[2] == 5:
                    thirdDigit = "D"
                if value[2] == 6:
                    thirdDigit = "DC"
                if value[2] == 7:
                    thirdDigit = "DCC"
                if value[2] == 8:
                    thirdDigit = "DCCC"
                if value[2] == 9:
                    thirdDigit = "CM"     
            if numLength == 4:
                if value[3] == 0:
                    fourthDigit = None
                if value[3] == 1:
                    fourthDigit = "M"
                if value[3] == 2:
                    fourthDigit = "MM"
                if value[3] == 3:
                    fourthDigit = "MMM"
                answer = (fourthDigit + thirdDigit + secondDigit + firstDigit)
            
        if numLength == 3:
            answer = (thirdDigit + secondDigit + firstDigit)
        
        if numLength == 2:
            answer = (secondDigit + firstDigit)
            
        if numLength == 1:
            answer = (firstDigit)
        
        return(answer)
```

The LeetCode problem is:

```
Roman numerals are represented by seven different symbols: I, V, X, L, C, D and M.

Symbol       Value
I             1
V             5
X             10
L             50
C             100
D             500
M             1000
For example, 2 is written as II in Roman numeral, just two one's added together. 12 is written as XII, which is simply X + II. The number 27 is written as XXVII, which is XX + V + II.

Roman numerals are usually written largest to smallest from left to right. However, the numeral for four is not IIII. Instead, the number four is written as IV. Because the one is before the five we subtract it making four. The same principle applies to the number nine, which is written as IX. There are six instances where subtraction is used:

I can be placed before V (5) and X (10) to make 4 and 9. 
X can be placed before L (50) and C (100) to make 40 and 90. 
C can be placed before D (500) and M (1000) to make 400 and 900.
Given an integer, convert it to a roman numeral.
```

Any comments about my general approach to solving the problem are welcome as well.

Note regarding the question being closed as duplicate -- none of the linked articles deal with Python enumerate() or answer my question, as far as I can tell.

Comment: `value[0]` is giving you the error. `value` is an `int`, therefore it is not suscriptable. What I suppose you want is compare like so `if value == 0` and so on

Comment: Your code will be 1/10th as long if you use a dict to map these values rather than a series of if statements.

Comment: @CamiloMartínez What I'm looking for is the value of index 0, which is the first item returned by enumerate().  So, the enumerated list for [3, 9, 7, 9] would look like this, for example:

[0, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 9, 7, 9]

And so when I say value[0], what I'm trying to get is 3, when I say value[1], I'm trying to get 9, and so on.

Comment: You said `for count, value in enumerate()`. `count` IS the variable with your indeces. `value` contains your actual values and you don't need to do anything to those, except check what the value is.

Comment: @CamiloMartínez Ah, thank you.  I see what you mean now.